# Send Image from Flask to HTML is not successful

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

I would like to send image with `Flask` app when I click to predict button in my `html` code.
Code is supposed to get prompt and run ML model and generate image based on input prompt. I can generate the picture but somehow I can not send it to html or html doesn't show the image.
Anyone can check my `flask` and `html` code where the problem is ? My `flask` image send method is wrong or `html` part is wrong ? How to show the image in `html` ?

```
import os
import io
import base64
from PIL import Image
import torch
from torch import autocast
from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline, LMSDiscreteScheduler
import transformers
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

lms = LMSDiscreteScheduler(
    beta_start=0.00085,
    beta_end=0.012,
    beta_schedule="scaled_linear"
    )
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(
    "CompVis/stable-diffusion-v1-4",
    scheduler=lms,
    use_auth_token=True,
    cache_dir=os.getenv("cache_dir", "./models")
    ).to("cuda")

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])

def page_template():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])

def predict():
    prompt_text = request.form['word']
    with autocast("cuda"):
        image = pipe(prompt_text)["sample"][0]
        data = io.BytesIO()
        image.save(data, "JPEG")
        encoded_img_data = base64.b64encode(data.getvalue())
    return render_template("index.html", img_data=encoded_img_data.decode('utf-8'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tutorial</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1 class="text-center">Stable Diffusion</h1>

        <form class="p-3 text-center" action='/', method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <label for="promptfield" class="form-label">StableDiffusionPrompt</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="promptfield" name="word" placeholder="Please enter your prompt" />


            <input class="form-control" type="file" name="imagefile" >
            <input class="btn btn-primary mt-3" type="submit" value="Predict Image" >
        </form>
        
        {% if prediction %}
            <img id="picture" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ img_data }}">
            <p> img id="picture" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ img_data }}"</p>
        {% endif %}
        
    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: Could you print the img_data=encoded_img_data.decode('utf-8') and show me the output of it, please? Just to make sure how it is decoded.

Answer (score -2):

here is the output of `encoded_img_data.decode('utf-8')`.

[image]

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zFXBgdmYkn_pqA_XDVRUe509uWShluvQ/view?usp=sharing